# Как прикрутить props к компоненту

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Компонент посредник получает через пропс "дочерний" компонент. Да - вот так, не я делал. В компоненте посреднике он вытаскивается из пропса и вставляется в определенное место посредника. DataOne уже используется в дочернем. Как в компоненте посреднике добавить дочернему компоненту добавить ещё один пропс. Это похоже на HOC. С некоторыми отличиями. Компонент посредник получает дочерний компонент (с пропсами для дочернего) через пропс и включает его в свое дерево компонентов. Надо в посреднике ещё один пропс дочернему отправить.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте создать копию элемента при помощи `React.cloneElement()`

Например:

`React.cloneElement(props.element, { newProp: newPropValue })`